# javascript on mouse and key down/up event combined

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, keyboard-events

I am trying to create a keyboard + mouse-click shortcut to execute a code.

In the example below when I click the mouse button it will return var mouseDown as 1.

Then if mouseDown equals 1 and keyboard key shift is pressed I'd like the alert message to appear.

**Keyboard + mouse-click event that fails:**

```js
var mouseDown = 0;
document.onmousedown = function(e) {
    if (e.which == 1) { //Left mouse button on Mac
 mouseDown = 1;}
 else {
 mouseDown = 0;}
};

if (mouseDown == 1) {
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.which == 16) { //Shift key on Mac
 alert("Shift + mouse was pressed");
 mouseDown = 0;
 }
};
}
```

**Mouse-click event alone works:**

```js
document.onmousedown = function(e) {
    if (e.which == 1) {
 alert("Mouse was pressed");
 }
};
```

**Shift-key event alone works:**

```js
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.which == 16) {
 alert("Shift was pressed");
 }
};
```

Comment: If you have never logged the event object to console...is worth looking at it. Lots of properties in it. Hard to remember them all...just good to know about them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this

```js
document.onmousedown = function(e) {
  if (e.shiftKey && e.which == 1) {
  alert("Mouse and Shift was pressed");
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Abolix! I did try almost the same at first, but failed. Do you know why it would fail if I use **onkeydown** instead of **onmousedown** for above example?