# MouseDown doesn't get capture immediately after pressing Shift key with some alphabet

Tags: reactjs, canvas, onkeydown, onmousedown

I was trying to create a drawing app using react and canvas. For that, I needed to capture KeyDown and MouseDown events on canvas for cursor coordinates. So, I created a handler on Keydown that will select a command like a circle, etc... So, the key used to enter the command key is `SHIFT+CTRL`. But, when I enter SHIFT+CTRL and then any normal key, the canvas doesn't capture the MouseDown event for some seconds. The same is happening when I am using `SHIFT+Alphabet`.

I also checked whether any component is being rendered during the process. But it wasn't.
I haven't used `stopPropagation` or `preventDefault` on any of the event handlers.

So, can someone help me out?

```
const DrawingCanvas = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const el = canvasRef.current;
    el.focus();
    el.height = window.innerHeight;
    el.width = window.innerWidth;
    el.style.cursor = 'crosshair';
    canvas.el = el;
    canvas.ctx = el.getContext('2d');
    window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
    window.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);
    window.addEventListener('resize', onResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
      window.removeEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);
      window.removeEventListener('resize', onResize);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='root-canvas'>
      <canvas
        className='drawing-canvas position-absolute'
        onMouseMove={onMouseMove}
        onMouseDown={onMouseDown}
        onMouseUp={onMouseUp}
        ref={canvasRef}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Edit:**
After further debugging, I found that the problem is producing because of alphabet keys (not because of SHIFT key). Whenever I pressed any Alphabet key canvas won't capture MouseDown event.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript on mouse and key down/up event combined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55598188/javascript-on-mouse-and-key-down-up-event-combined)

Comment: No. Because my scenario is like first I will press SHIFT+CTRL to enter into command mode. Then I will press corresponding key to select shape which will be drawn on the canvas. And after that the first ever mouseDown will start drawing the shape. For example take circle. So, SHIFT+CTRL -> C -> MouseDown for center and MouseMove to stretch radius. But, here MouseDown won't be captured for some seconds after C was pressed.

Comment: When you say press, do you mean "press and hold with mouse operation" or simply "press and release, then mouse operation"? Because if it's the former, there is no difference: then you should simply check for pressed keys in the MouseEvent.

Comment: First, I am "pressing and releasing" the Alphabet key. then trying to do a mouse-down event. So, at the time of the MouseDown event, there is no Key being pressed.

Comment: Then you need to store somewhere as a state or a ref that these key events have occurred, so in your mousedown event you know what “mode” you’re in.

Comment: @Terry The part of the mode is working (I am storing the mode). But the issue is with the mouse down which doesn't work for 1-2 seconds after Key (Press+Release) on Alphabet keys. Because I need it to start drawing immediately after the shape is set.

Comment: I think you need to create a [mcve] on codesandbox or the likes: the code you have in your question doesn’t show any of the logic you’ve mentioned at all, making it impossible to debug.